# Where can I change comment in Java class (template) in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, comments

In standard Java code I have comment:

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
```

Where can I change this comment in the template for the Eclipse IDE?

Answer (score 12):

> **You Project -> Properties -> Java Code Style -> Code Templates -> Comments -> Types -> Edit**

Then customize comments for your own choices.
[image]

Comment: I don't see comment string /** Called when the activity is first created. */ in this Window

Comment: I don't need Automatically add comment. I want  to change default string in Template.

Comment: I was confused that it's on the "Types" setting .. but it worked, thanks!  For IDE-wide support, it also works from Eclipse Preferences: Java -> Java Code Style -> Code Templates -> Comments -> Types -> Edit